# How to align equations that are in different items of an itemize

Tags: align, itemize

I want to align equations in an `align*` environment, that are on different `\item`s of an `itemize` environment. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item First item with equation:
   \begin{align*}
      a+b+c+d &= e,\\
      1+2+3+4 &= 5.
   \end{align*}
\item Second item without equation.
\item Third item with equation, that should be aligned with the equation
   of the first item:
   \begin{align*}
      x &= x, \\
      3 &= 3.
   \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While the duplicate effectively would have answered my question, I'd like to remark that it was unintuitive for me that `\item` may appear in `\intertext` or even `\shortintertext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item First item with equation:
   \begin{align*}
      a+b+c+d &= e,\\
      1+2+3+4 &= 5.\\
\shortintertext{%
  \item Second item without equation.
  \item Third item with equation, that should be aligned with the equation
   of the first item:%
}
      x &= x, \\
      3 &= 3.
   \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `\intertext`. Here is, again the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item First item with equation:
   \begin{align*}
      a+b+c+d &= e,\\
      1+2+3+4 &= 5.
   \end{align*}
\item Second item without equation.
\item Third item with equation, that should be aligned with the equation
   of the first item:
   \begin{align*}
      x &= x, \\
      3 &= 3.
   \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

Some other test for seraration.

\begin{itemize}
\item First item with equation:
   \begin{align*}
      a+b+c+d &= e,\\
      1+2+3+4 &= 5.
\intertext{      
\item Second item without equation.
\item Third item with equation, that should be aligned with the equation
   of the first item:
}
      x &= x, \\
      3 &= 3.
   \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Yielding the following:

---

[image: Output of the above MWE]

---

It can be seen that, unfortunately, the spaces at the beginning and at the end of the `\intertext` seem to be a little too big.